# Setting up qt4py2 with with python 2.7 in virtualenv - cannot find the files :(

Tags: python-2.7, installation, pyqt4

hopefully this question fits here, I have tried googling and reading "http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html" but unfortunately I'm such a newbie in all things linux that I cannot figure out what applies here...
anyway:

I have a virtual env (in Python 2.7)

I am trying to set up labelImg as instructed in : https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg, specifically I run (with my virtualenv active):

```
sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools
sudo pip install lxml (<- did run this as "pip install lxml")
```

Then I run into problems with this:

```
make qt4py2
```

I got error:

> "make: *** No rule to make target 'qt4py2'.  Stop."

Now from googling I got the impression that I should be in the same directory as the make file when I run make (is this even true?), but when I try to find where pyqt4 is, I cannot find the folder (it is not in `~/.virtualenvs/virP2/lib/python2.7/site-packages$` (`virP2` is the name of the virtualenv)

I have also tried to run (with the `virP2` still active)

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

but I got:

> "python-qt4 is already the newest version"

and I still cannot find where the directory with qt4 files is. (I also looked into the python2.7 folder outside the virtualenv, but it was not there)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: so I figured this out: as I probably should have realised, the PyQt4 lived in the `dist-packages` directory. And when I made a new virtualenv with `--system-site-package` switch active, I am able to use PyQt4.